# Maven Dependency Issue in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I am using the eclipse kepler version 4.3.2. I have recently checked out the java project from the svn repository. I have checked the project contains the pom.xml file but I am not able to build the project in the eclipse. I shows the various build errors such as

```
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE   pom.xml /RAWS   line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

Note:
I have the eclipse maven plugin installed in the eclipse because I can see the maven option in the dialogue box in the window->preferences option

How should I solve this issue ?Do I need to download the maven?How should I solved the issue of build errors? Do I need to download the new plugin ?
Can anybody tell me the steps than it would be helpful?

Comment: Try to update maven project.

Comment: You do have maven installed right? You can try using it command line :
mvn compile - to see if the project compiles, 
mvn eclipse:eclipse - to fix your eclipse project

Answer (score 1):

Update your maven project orelse Open the pom.xml with Maven POM Editor and you will find the Dependencies tab click that and add the required JARs in to your project

Answer (score 0):

As the desired jar is in MavenCentral, it is likely that your MavenCentral connection is not working. Either you replaced the MavenCentral url (in the settings.xml or your pom) or you live behind a proxy and MavenCentral cannot be seen.

In the "Maven repositories" view in Eclipse, you can see the indices of the repositories. Check whether central has an index there (after possibly applying "Update Index" on it).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should give us more informations about your problem.

Maybe you could post some snippets of your pom.xml or tell us which repository you try to access?

It's also possible that your maven version is too old/new.